# Обновил Android Studio, проект не запускается, выдаётся ошибка

Tags: android, android-studio

Проект создавался в Android Studio 1.5, после Android Studio обновил до 2.1, проект перестал запускаться, стали появляться ошибки.

1. Rendering Error(Problems) (смотрел в интернете варианты решения, но не чего не помогло API ставил меньше, безуспешно)
2. Ошибка при компиляции(запуске)

   > Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
   >   Could not open local jar classpath snapshot write cache (C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\ProFormuls1.0.gradle\2.14.1\tasks_app_compileDebugJavaWithJavac\localJarClasspathSnapshot).
   >   Unexpected lock protocol found in lock file. Expected 3, found 0.

К второму пункту, тоже очень много искал возможностей решения, но не помогло ничего.

Вот код Gradle:

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


 android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.studio.user.proformuls10"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 4
    versionName "1.3"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
}
```

Comment: можете попробовать пере-импортировать проект.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Удаляй папку

> c: \ users \ [myusername] \ .gradle \ 2.14.1

И перезапускай после этого студию

Comment: не помогло, такая же ошибка при эмуляции на устройстве

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: всё получилось, есть папка gradle в c:/users/user и там тоже есть папка 2.14.1, но удалять надо было не тут, а в папке проекта